# How predict function works

Tags: r

Iam using this command in R for building decision trees :

```
> library(party) 
> ind = sample(2,nrow(iris),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.8,0.2))
> myFormula <- Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
> iris_ctree <- ctree(myFormula,data = iris[ind==1,])
> predict(iris_ctree)
```

What exactly does predict function compute and how does it perform the computation?

Comment: Have you read the description? try typing ?predict into the R-interactive console.

Comment: Yes i read the description but it isn't detailed.The line where it says "Some considerable attempts are made to match up the columns in
‘newdata’ to those used for fitting" is not very clear.

Comment: what that means is, that the predict function tries to intelligently recognize which columns of the out-of-sample data ("newdata") correspond to the training data ("those used for fitting").

Comment: Okay, So in context of the example posted above what exactly would the predict(iris_ctree) function do??

Answer (score 1):

the example first constructs "ind" based on a sampling of 1's with probability .8 and 2's with probability .2. It then specifies a Formula that defines the hypothesis function for the model. It then fits the conditional inference tree to the estimate the parameters based on the hypothesis specification using the sampled data - which is just the data containing 1's.

It then runs a prediction based on the full sample of 1's and 2's.

So basically it trained on 1's, but runs predict on 1's and 2's.

Comment: yes the ctree function uses the sampled data containig just 1's but the predict function has the same number of observations as the sapmled data. So how does the predict runs on 1's and 2's both??

Comment: what's so outlandish about that ? It TRAINED the model on data that constituted just the 1's, but is trying to PREDICT the 2's (and the 1'st) based on the trained parameters.

Comment: OHk , Thanks @Aditya Sihag

Comment: @Ankita if this solves your problem please upvote and tick mark answer :)